# Variant vs GADT approach

Tags: ocaml, variant, gadt

In OCaml, I want to define a function `f` that accepts an `input` to update a record `x`. Among the following two approaches, I'm interested whether one has an advantage over the other (readability aside).

**Variant approach**

```
type input =
  | A of int
  | B of string

let f x = function
  | A a -> { x with a }
  | B b -> { x with b }
```

**GADT approach**

```
type _ input =
  | A : int input
  | B : string input

let f (type t) x (i: t input) (v: t) =
  match i with
  | A -> { x with a = v }
  | B -> { x with b = v }
```

Comment: The variant approach has the huge advantage of being simple, straightforward and easy to understand, in both implementation and use. The GADT approach can however be partially applied wth the type of `input` without also providing the value, but that's only an advantage if you actually need it. The answer to questions like this almost always depend heavily on context because there's almost always trade-offs. If there weren't, there would be no need for the less advantageous feature.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that would be the case. Probably should've worded my question as "pros and cons of each". Having a bit of trouble identifying use cases of GADTs, other than parsing data constructs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADT pros:

- Straightforward, no need for type annotations or anything fancy
- Writing a function of type `string -> input` is straightforward.

GADT pros:

- Avoid one layer of boxing.
  However, this is completely negated if you need a parsing functions, which would force you to pack things under an existential.

---

To be more precise, the GADT version can be seen as a decomposition of the ADT version. You can transform one into the other in a systematic way, and the memory layout will be similar (with the help of a small annotation):

```
type a and b and c

type sum =
  | A of a
  | B of b
  | C of c

type _ tag =
  | A : a tag
  | B : b tag
  | C : c tag

type deppair = Pair : ('a tag * 'a) -> deppair [@@ocaml.unboxed]

let pack (type x) (tag : x tag) (x : x) = Pair (tag, x)
let to_sum (Pair (tag, v)) : sum = match tag with
  | A -> A v
  | B -> B v
  | C -> C v

let of_sum : sum -> deppair = function
  | A x -> pack A x
  | B x -> pack B x
  | C x -> pack C x
```

Comment: Boxing as in memory representation?

Comment: That notation is new to me :) Is `[@@ocaml.unboxed]` a type constraint indicating that `deppair` cannot be used with existential values?

Comment: Not at all, It's an annotation that indicates to the compiler that the memory representation should be optimized. See http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec260

Comment: So as to clarify the terminology used here, is `type deppair` which wraps the main gadt type,  the existential here? Also is this the general pattern when using GADT, i.e. one always has to wrap/unwrap a gadt inside an 'existential' to simulate normal ADT functions?

Comment: @Drup The GADT is represented as block with a tag containing the arguments as fields. Just like an ADT. So where do you say there is one less layer of boxing? Actually in your code the ADT is a block with tag and one field while the Pair is a block with tag and two pairs. Isn't that wasting memory here?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow If you look at the original `f` function posted in the question, the ADT version has two level of indirection to reach `string` (one pointer to the constructor, which contains a pointer). The GADT version shaves one layer of that, by taking two arguments: one containing the constructor, and the other containing a direct pointer. In the code above, I simply show how you can move from one representation to the other in a systematic manner.

Comment: @BikalLem No, my code just shows how you can move from one representation to another, but you don't have to. It is simply a demonstration that GADTs are, in a way, more refined: you can always break down ADTs into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed (non)readability of GADTs is a big drawback. Try to avoid GADTs when possibly. Easier to type and easier to read. Less complex error messages too.

Simplified at runtime they are the same. They are represented as simple ints or blocks with tag and fields and the code uses the tag to match and branch. So neither gives you an advantage there.

At compile time GADTs are more powerful as the compiler can check types in ways that ADTs don't allow. One example are existential types like the example in the other answer. So use GADTs when you can't use ADTs.